# How to create excel's pivot table using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a tabular data in one sheet. I need to create a pivot table with filters on top using the data and insert the pivot table in another sheet in same workbook.

I came across multiple ways to pivot a table using pandas but all of them are actual pivot and not excel's pivot. I need to the pivot table to still refer the other sheet for data and have filter at top of the pivot table with all the excel's pivot table functionalities.

Is this possible using python? If yes, which library and function?

Comment: Does this work for you? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: No, This does not solve the excel filter issue. Also, it won't make the pivot table editable (like adding columns, rows, values, filter)

Comment: Gotcha.  I think I might not understand what you'd like to do, but another module might be the `openpyxl` package. It has a pivot table section here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pivot.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the groupby functions yet? This allows us to group by the variable of your choice and you can perform mathematical calculations on the groupings.

```
df.groupby(by=["b"], dropna=False).sum()
```

Documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: That does not solve the excel filter issue. Also, it won't make the pivot table editable (like adding columns, rows, values, filter)